# How to draw a horizontal Combined Chart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: mpandroidchart

How to draw a horizontal Combined Chart in MPAndroidChart?

I know how to draw a horizontal stacked bar chart and working perfect. Now, i need add bubbles on this view. How could i achieve this? BTW, How could I manage the bubble size (not depends on the value)?

Comment: How did you managed to draw a horizontal stacked bar chart? i am using the same library for charts

Answer (score 0):

ATM this is not possible with `HorizontalBarChart`, just normal.